# type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'String' error in Dart

Tags: android, dart, flutter

Neither The print statement nor anything below it run, and the error message points to the issue being the last line above starting with `var time`. I also verified that `earthquakes` is a growableList, which means that `earthquakes[0]` should run without issue, but it doesn't... What am I doing wrong? Let me know if the question needs more clarification and I'll provide it.
Link to [gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9QESb.jpg) of error
Link to [code](https://github.com/ThinkDigitalRepair/Quake/blob/master/quake/lib/ui/quake.dart) on GitHub

The problematic part of my code is as follows. Error reported on line 43.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

class Quake extends StatefulWidget {
  var _data;

  Quake(this._data);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => new QuakeState(_data);
}

class QuakeState extends State<Quake> {
  // https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/all_day.geojson


//      "https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/all_day.geojson";
  var _data;


  QuakeState(this._data);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
//    debugPrint(_data['features'].runtimeType.toString());

    List earthquakes = _data['features'];
    return new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: new Text("Quakes - USGS All Earthquakes"),
          backgroundColor: Colors.red,
          centerTitle: true,
        ),
        body: new ListView.builder(
            itemCount: earthquakes.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              print("${earthquakes[index]}");

              var earthquake = earthquakes[index];
              var time = earthquake['properties']['time'];
              time *= 1000;

              //var dateTime = new DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(int.parse(time));
              //time = new DateFormat.yMMMMd(dateTime).add_jm();
              return new ListTile(
                title: new Text(time ?? "Empty"),
              );
            }));
  }
}

Future<Map> getJson(String url) async {
  return await http.get(url).then((response) => json.decode(response.body));
}
```

Comment: What line points the exception to?

Comment: I assume `earthquakes` is a `Map`, not a `List`

Comment: It's a list of maps from how I understand it.
Line: 14 of this file. https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/all_day.geojson

I also added a link to the repo and the error number to the post

Comment: What line exactly causes the error? I can't reproduce.

Comment: That's what's confusing me.  It doesn't make sense. It could be telling me something else and not be clear enough to debug correctly. Please check the post again for a gif of the error.

Comment: I don't think the code that causes the error is included in the question. Probably further down in the `itemBuilder` callback method.

Comment: OK. I don't either now. I added the full code now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171639/discussion-between-thinkdigital-and-gunter-zochbauer).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
title: new Text(time ?? "Empty"),
```

should be

```
title: new Text(time != null ? '$time' : "Empty"),
```

or

```
title: new Text('${time ?? "Empty"}'),
```

Comment: I don't believe this will work as intended.  If time is null, then `'${time}'` will evaluate to `"null"` (a string) and that will be used instead of `"Empty"`

Comment: That was it!!! Thank you. So the flutter error wasn't definitive enough, right?
@Stephen you are right, it does show null, but I can fix that.

Comment: So since time, an int, isn't a String, it couldn't convert it if time was not null. Got it.

Answer (score 3):

As the above answers pointed, the `time` variable was `int` while the `Text()` required an `String`.

There might be another issue:
If the `time` was `null`, the null-aware operator `??` will not work as expected. Because the `time` variable was used before the `??` in `time *= 1000` expression.

Therefore, the `time *= 1000` should be deleted, and the `Text` should be like

`Text(time == null ? "Empty" : '${time * 1000}')`

Note: The `time` was not modified in this case.

Answer (score 2):

The code in following line from your snippet is:

```
title: new Text(time ?? "Empty"),
```

While, it should actually look like following:

```
title: new Text(time?.toString() ?? "Empty"),
```

Answer (score 2):

Although the original question has been well answered, I want to show the type issue that caused the problem.

`time` has been declared as an *int*

`Text()` requires a **String**

When the `time ?? "Empty"` evaluates to `time` the type is *int*, which will cause the `Text()` to receive the wrong type.

Anytime the `type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int'` message shows, there has been a type mismatch.

Answer (score 2):

This is because you are using the int value where the string should be used. Use int value or cast it to string as **intValueName.toString();**

Answer (score -1):

just check if you change the order of (context, index) at the itemBuilder of ListBuilder bye

Comment: While this may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer as it will attract more upvotes. Try formatting your answer correctly and excluding words such as `bye`.